# How to validate yield return default in IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ienumerable

I am trying to check whether `IEnumerable<>` is null or empty but somehow my if check always fails whenever it is empty.

```
    private bool Update()
    {
        IEnumerable<RecordHolder> recordHolders = GetData();
        // below  check doesn't work
        if (recordHolders == null || !recordHolders.Any())
            return false;

        // .. some other code
    }

    public IEnumerable<RecordHolder> GetData()
    {
        var isSuccess = PullRemote(url);
        if (!isSuccess.Result) { yield return default; }

        // .. some other code
    }
```

Whenever my `GetData()` method returns `yield return default` then the subsequent `if` check in `Update` method doesn't work. Anything wrong I am doing?

I thought my if check in `Update` method will be able to catch `yield return default` but I am wrong looks like.

Comment: Did you try with `yield break;`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `yield break` instead of `yield return default`. Alternatively, you can do the first part of the operation in a *regular* method (not an iterator block), and special-case the return for failure cases (`Array.Empty<T>()` is a common choice), deferring to an iterator block (or a `Select` projection) for the success cases.

Comment: I got confuse now. If possible can you provide an example with my code like what should I do here? It will help me to understand better. Are you suggesting I should just use `yield break` there? That's it? or you saying I should change this whole method and use normal list here?

Comment: @john I gave both options :) try the yield break one first - it is simpler

Answer (score 0):

When you do yield return default you are returning the default value of RecordHolder which is null.

So your IEnumerable will contain 1 item which is null.

Try returning Enumerable.Empty() or Array.Empty(); instead of your yield return default.

Example

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
{
    var result = GetData();
    Console.WriteLine(result.Count()); // Prints 1
}

public static IEnumerable<MyClass> GetData()
{
    yield return default;
}

public class MyClass
{
        public string MyProperty {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vVefPx

Comment: Also, `yield return default` doesn't terminate the sequence, so whatever "some other code" does: will still happen - this means we don't know what results may or may not come *after* the default

Comment: @MarcGravell there's no loop, `yield return default` will be executed only once, thus there's only one item in the sequence. `.GetEnumerator()` > `.MoveNext()` (`true`) > `.Current` (`default`) > `.MoveNext()` (`false`).

Comment: @aepot I'm talking about the code in the original post; since there isn't an "else", **whatever other things the method does**: will happen, i.e. "// .. some other code"